How to increase vertical space in beamer bibliography?

Could you explain how to obtain above spacing of bibliography? My MWE is
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{bolte2024swarm,
  title={Swarm gradient dynamics for global optimization: the mean-field limit case},
  author={Bolte, J{\'e}r{\^o}me and Miclo, Laurent and Villeneuve, St{\'e}phane},
  journal={Mathematical Programming},
  volume={205},
  number={1},
  pages={661--701},
  year={2024},
  publisher={Springer}
}
@article{wang2023singular,
  title={Singular density dependent stochastic differential equations},
  author={Wang, Feng-Yu},
  journal={Journal of Differential Equations},
  volume={361},
  pages={562--589},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{hao_strong_2024,
    title = {Strong {Convergence} of {Propagation} of {Chaos} for {McKean}–{Vlasov} {SDEs} with {Singular} {Interactions}},
    volume = {56},
    issn = {0036-1410, 1095-7154},
    url = {https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/23M1556666},
    doi = {10.1137/23M1556666},
    language = {en},
    number = {2},
    urldate = {2024-03-31},
    journal = {SIAM Journal on Mathematical Analysis},
    author = {Hao, Zimo and Röckner, Michael and Zhang, Xicheng},
    month = apr,
    year = {2024},
    pages = {2661--2713}
}
@misc{zhang_second_2022,
    title = {Second order {McKean}-{Vlasov} {SDEs} and kinetic {Fokker}-{Planck}-{Kolmogorov} equations},
    url = {http://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01273},
    urldate = {2024-07-27},
    publisher = {arXiv},
    author = {Zhang, Xicheng},
    month = jan,
    year = {2022},
    note = {arXiv:2109.01273 [math]}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{HTML}{eaeff2}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=anti-flashwhite}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.35cm,text margin right=0.35cm}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\gdef\beamer@frametitle{}}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage[
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false,
  eprint=false,
  sorting=none,
  style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\renewcommand\bibfont{\scriptsize}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Our contribution}

We found only three papers: \cite{bolte2024swarm,wang2023singular,hao_strong_2024,zhang_second_2022}.

\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}{}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]{References}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Place \setlength{\bibitemsep}{1ex plus 2pt minus 2pt} after load biblatex but before \printbibliography (the end of the preamble is a fine place for that).
Of course, feel free to change the length to your personal preference.

